# Continuous run of Glue Jobs

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue

I designed a simple solution where I just want my lambda function to trigger Glue job whenever user places CSV files in S3 bucket ( User will submit CSV files only once a day). My glue job runs fines but it is triggering continuously even if user is submitting files once only.

I just want that my lambda function trigger Glue job once for one instance of file submission by users. Ho to achieve this?

Thanks.

Avoiding continuous run of glue job. Want to trigger job once based on S3 event --> SNS -- > Lamdba --> Glue job trigger

Comment: Have you considered using EventBridge rules to trigger the job directly: 
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/starting-workflow-eventbridge.html
* https://repost.aws/questions/QUsQRxOITUR_qj2uAe3_NUoA/questions/QUsQRxOITUR_qj2uAe3_NUoA/trigger-glue-job-from-s3?